# Logitech USB headset not working in 14.04

Tags: sound, usb, pulseaudio, speakers, logitech

I recently converted my laptop to Ubuntu 14.04 (two days ago at the time of this posting) and just encountered this problem (an hour or so ago at the time of this posting). The problem is that my Logitech headset is no longer working, but in the weirdest way possible. The sound control tab in the system settings shows the headset as the selected audio device but all the sound is played through the onboard speakers of my acer aspire 4743. all of the other functions of the headset remain the same (microphone and volume controls.). I have already messed around with alsamixer and tried the suggestions of other users but nothing has worked so far, any ideas?
I am totally new to Linux and have no idea what might be causing this.
Thanks,
Eric

Comment: Update, sevral reboots and an update solved the problem, All is well

Comment: I've had this happen with a Logitech H800. Just rebooting fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

It's only because your hardware mapping is not configured automatically by your Ubuntu. You can solve this manually.

1. Find whether your system is showing your **Logitech USB headset** or not.

   Go to **Settings** > **Sound**:

   [image: Screenshot: sound settings]
2. This will be here, go to the terminal, type this command:

   ```
   xinput list
   ```
3. Enable your device by putting its ID at place 13 in code with this command:

   ```
   xinput set-prop 13 "Device Enabled" 0
   ```

   Like this - see the last line:

   [image: Screensot: output of <code>xinput</code> commands]

Comment: This will disable the device.

Comment: In my case, I can not see my headset as Output. Would you please guide me to install any specific libraries. I have run Ubuntu 14.04 64bit and Logitech wireless headset H800.

Comment: I only needed Step 1 with my Logitech G533 =)

Comment: What does that command actually do? Why does the headset have to be id 13? I've read the man page but it's still not clear.